How to add a rule for empty strings in i18n Vue
I have a vue app that uses vue-i18n, and some dynamic components that set the label for table headers, with some of them blank, the problem is that im getting the warning:
[intlify] Not found '' key in 'en' locale messages.
the table is based on:
//template 
<th v-for="header in headers" class="text-center">
  {{ $t(header.label) }}
</th>

//script

const header = [
  { label: "sector", show: "always" },
  { label: "price", show: "left" },
  { label: "", show: "right" },
  { label: "forecastTicket", show: "right" },
  { label: "forecastSales", show: "right" },
  { label: "ticketPrice", show: "right" },
  { label: "elasticity", show: "right" },
  { label: "", show: "left" },
];

As some of the table labels are empty strings, I don't want to modify all the tables to use or not the translate function
i've tried adding the message:
['']: ''
the solution i've come to is changing the blank string to something like '--empty--', but i'd like to keep it clean with the empty label, is this possible?

A warning is not a big deal. Here is the fallback page if you one day have something more serious going on in terms of errors.

Yes, its not a serious issue, is just intended for clean the warning messages

Instead of adding a rule you could just check if label is empty.
<template>
  <th v-for="header in headers" class="text-center">
    {{ header.label.length ? $t(header.label) : "" }}
  </th>
</template>

From a performance perspective that is more efficient since you don't have to call another function.

Thanks, is another solution, but even i'd like to know if the case of just adding the blank is possible

A simple check could do the job:
{{ header.label == '' ? '' : $t(header.label) }}


Thanks, is another solution, but even i'd like to know if the case of just adding the blank is possible

The JSON standard RFC 8259 says the name (key) of the JSON should be unique. While RFC 8259 does not directly prohibit empty strings as keys, its description implies that keys should be non-empty strings.
